# managed metadata columns and filtering

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, term-store, term-set, sharepoint-list-filter

I use some term sets to be used in columns.

The term sets are hiearchically nested with several levels.

E.g.

- Machine

  - Mechanics

    - Frame

      - Bottom
      - Lid
      - Lid bolts
    - Structure

      - Plate 1
      - Plate 2
      - Fixture
  - Electronics

    - Assembly 1

      - Power supply

        - Transformer
        - Rectifier
      - CPU
    - Assembly 2

      - Storage
      - Backup storage

Users can select multiple terms out of this for every list entry. However when filtering I want that filtering will succeed if the filter selection is equal to the term but also when it's superseding it.

E.g. I want that when I filter for "Assembly 1" I get all occurrences of

- Assembly 1
- Power supply
- Transformer
- Rectifier
- CPU

is that possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, when we select only one root term, I don't think we can filter all the sub-terms contained in the root term.

It's necessary to choose all single terms you need, then filter the list view based on them.

**------------------------Update-----------------------**

If you are in the sharepoint online **modern experience**, it's necessary to choose all terms for filter.
[image]
If you are using **classic experience**, we could filter the metadata column by clicking **include descendants** option, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I'm asking because I think that some years ago I had observed the behaviour I want. But I 'm not sure.

Comment: I have updated the reply, please check it.

Comment: Ah! That's what I was looking for. Great!!!! I hope that this feature will be added to the new experience some day.