# Filtering with managed metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata

Using SharePoint online, I have created a simple site level managed metadata hierarchy.  When I filter using that column, I want to select everything that is below a certain level.  However, when I check the box in tree view, it does not select everything beneath it, just the level I have selected.  Is there any option to select all levels below (without checking each box individually)?

So if I wanted to see all documents under OPS.30 - Weighbridge, here's what I want, just by selecting the top level;

[image: Desired result]

What I get;

[image: Actual result]

Which only returns documents actually tagged at the highest level.

This may seem trivial, but there could be 10 levels below each sub level, so that's a lot of clicking to get what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the sharepoint online **modern experience**, this is by design and no OOB way to meet your requirement.

As a workaround, when we return to **classic experience**, we could filter the metadata column by clicking **include descendants** option, as shown below:

[image]

Please refer to the similar issue:

[managed metadata columns and filtering](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/291120/managed-metadata-columns-and-filtering)

Comment: Thanks Julie, disappointing we have to go back to classic, but it's an option!

Answer (score 1):

This problem can also be addressed by the taxonomy design. Similar to your requirement, we wanted documents tagged with all child terms to be returned when a user enters a term in the text field (which BTW I highly recommend as a supplement to the tree). We achieved the desired results by always tagging the document with the parent terms of whatever terms were being used. So, if I tag the document with term A.1.2, then I will also tag the document with its parent term A.1 and also with its parent term A.

A
A.1
A.1.1
A.1.2
A.2
A.3
B
C